# What programming language should I study to know WordPress very well?

Tags: language

I want to know WordPress structure and functions very well.

So what programming language should I study to know WordPress very well? PHP?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress functions are PHP. you should start here: https://developer.wordpress.org/

As the first steps I recommend to study:

Theme development: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

The Loop: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

And The WP theme hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: This is correct but JavaScript and associated libraries are also becoming an ever increasing necessity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can learn below in order to reach wordpress theme and plugin development.

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript
- PHP with Database (MySQL)

Once you have some basic knowledge of all the above things. Then you can do coding and development into WordPress. I would suggest first you can make a simple core php project so you will get some ideas how websites are working.